# Screen gets split into two parts (left and right) and these parts gets swapped

Tags: linux, qt

I am developing an application on SBC6000x board (with Linux kernel version 2.6.24). I am using Qt version 4.7.3. Application executable size is around 1.8 MB.

When I load an application on the board, most of the times it works fine but a few times the screen gets split into two parts (left and right).

After splitting, left and right parts get swapped. Interestingly, click events are handled according to original screen (before split).

I read, there is problem with display with Qt 4.7.3 version but not able to figure it out.

What could be the possible ways to handle this?

Comment: I think this belongs on Superuser.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am rotating my screen(180 degrees) for application need.
This is the command I use for rotation.

./app -qws -display transformed:Rot180 > /dev/null 2>&1 &

As per my opinion following could be possible reasons.
1. It has to do something with Frame Buffer (Refresh is not happening)? 
2. Processor is not enough powerful to handle this application rotation and hence causes problem